# How to select <li> element by hovering and clicking over them in a <ul> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-lists

I am trying to make a live search for the products of a specified supplier.

I have an **input element** with the Supplier Name to be entered in it:

```
<input title="supplier">
```

I have the following **Input Element** and **Un-Ordered List Element**

```
Live Product Search <input type="search" name="search" id="search">
<ul id="here" style="position: fixed; background-color: white; width:175px; height:300px; border: 1px solid grey; display:none; padding:0px 0px 10px 10px; "></ul>
```

I am populating **ul element** dynamically with live **list elements** from database using JQuery $.ajax and JQuery .keyup() function.

Javascript and JQuery for this purpose is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
var y=$('[title="supplier"]').val();        
        $("#here").show();
        var x =$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:'getdataforproductslive.php',
            data:{q: x, s: y},  
            success:function(p)
            {
var pr= p.split("|");
for (var option in pr){
var newLi = document.createElement("li");
newLi.innerHTML=pr[option];
{$("#here").append(newLi);}}},
});
$("#here").html("");
});
})
$("#search").blur(function(){$("#here").hide();})
```

This whole setup is populating the **ul element** with the product names as **li elements**, *but I do not know how to select one of these products or **li elements** and pass it to another input element in another table, which is supposed to use the product name*.

Can anyone guide me as to how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var sampleData = ['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3'];

 function setSupplier() {
  $('#supplier').val($(this).text());
 }
 $("#search").on('input keyup', function () {
  var val = $(this).val().trim();
  if (!val.length) {
   $("#here").empty().hide();
   return;
  }
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two',
   data: {
    q: val
   },
   success: function (res) {
    $("#here").empty().show();
    if ($("#here").data('state') === 'focusout') {
     $("#here").hide();
     return;
    }
    var items = sampleData.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     var li = $(document.createElement("li")).html(items[i] + ' ( ' + val + ' )').appendTo("#here");
     li.on('mousedown', setSupplier);
    }
   }
  });
 }).on('focusin', function () {
  if ($("#here").children().length) {
   $("#here").show();
  }
  $("#here").data('state', 'focusin');
 }).on('focusout', function () {
  if (!$(this).val().trim().length) {
   $("#here").empty();
  }
  $("#here").data('state', 'focusout').hide();
 });
```

```css
#here li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#here {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type a supplier name">
<input type="input" id="supplier" style="margin-top: 20px" readonly>

<ul id="here" style="position: fixed; background-color: white; width:175px; height:300px; border: 1px solid grey; display:none;"></ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abdullah Aydin, this will Inshallah work for me.